# How can I get the output of an application via ADB?

Tags: adb

I would like to get the text output of Google Voice2Text feature [Android9] via `adb`.  The one you get when clicking the microphone on the keyboard (Google Voice Typing in the pref panel).

I tried `adb logcat` to debug and it seems `com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search` is the one.

But on the output of `adb logcat --pid=PID`, I get many things, but no "text data", and a bunch of errors by the way.
But `logcat` is surely not the right tool.

How would you do this?

The logcat output:

```
    └─$ adb logcat --pid=16481
--------- beginning of main
12-28 05:23:00.205 +0000 16481 16481 D ViewRootImpl@dae9332[InputMethod]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
12-28 05:23:00.246 +0000 16481 16481 D ViewRootImpl@dae9332[InputMethod]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
12-28 05:23:00.248 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : #restart
12-28 05:23:00.249 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : #finishRecognition
12-28 05:23:00.249 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : #cancelRecognition
12-28 05:23:00.249 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : #cancel
12-28 05:23:00.249 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : #failWithException
12-28 05:23:00.250 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : Offline recognizer - stop detection
12-28 05:23:00.251 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : #startListening
12-28 05:23:00.251 +0000 16481 16596 W A       : (REDACTED) #onError space %s code %d!
12-28 05:23:00.251 +0000 16481 16596 W A       : #onError already finished - ignoring
12-28 05:23:00.253 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #onCreateView, request-id = %d
12-28 05:23:00.254 +0000 16481 16573 I ALT.AFClient: (REDACTED) #audio# acquire audio focus for client(%s)
12-28 05:23:00.254 +0000 16481 16573 I ALT.AFCSessionMgr: (REDACTED) #audio# acquire audio focus for client(%s) session(token(%d))
12-28 05:23:00.257 +0000 16481 16573 I ALT.ARCProvider: (REDACTED) #audio# activate audio request client(%s) and start listening
12-28 05:23:00.257 +0000 16481 16573 I ALT.ARCProvider: (REDACTED) #audio# activate audio request client(%s)
12-28 05:23:00.257 +0000 16481 16573 I ALT.ClientsMgr: (REDACTED) #audio# deactivate(status(%s)) client(name(%s), token(%d))
12-28 05:23:00.258 +0000 16481 16573 I ALT.ARCRoutingMgr: (REDACTED) #audio# disconnect(reason(%s)) audio route(%s)
12-28 05:23:00.258 +0000 16481 16573 I ALT.ClientsMgr: (REDACTED) #audio# activate audio request client(name(%s), token(%d))
12-28 05:23:00.259 +0000 16481 16573 I ALT.ARClient: (REDACTED) #audio# start listening for audio request client(token(%s))
12-28 05:23:00.261 +0000 16481 16573 I ALT.ARCSessionMgr: (REDACTED) #audio# audio request client(token(%d)) session(token(%d)) is being started on route(%s)
12-28 05:23:00.261 +0000 16481 16573 I ALT.SourceMgr: (REDACTED) #audio# audio request client(token(%d)) session(token(%d)) is being started
12-28 05:23:00.262 +0000 16481 16573 I ALT.SourceSequencer: (REDACTED) #audio# open audio source(%s)
12-28 05:23:00.265 +0000 16481 25695 I ALT.AudioRecordSource: (REDACTED) #audio# open audio source(%s)
12-28 05:23:00.266 +0000 16481 25695 I ALT.AudioRecordFactory: #audio# createAudioRecord
12-28 05:23:00.266 +0000 16481 16588 I ALT.AudioEventsHolder: (REDACTED) #audio# audio focus session(token(%d)) acquire status(%s)
12-28 05:23:00.266 +0000 16481 16591 I A       : (REDACTED) Audio focus acquiring status: %s
12-28 05:23:00.267 +0000 16481 16573 I A       : Online recognizer - start listening
12-28 05:23:00.272 +0000 16481 16573 I A       : Offline recognizer - start listening
12-28 05:23:00.273 +0000 16481 25697 W A       : (REDACTED) %s
12-28 05:23:00.273 +0000 16481 16573 I A       : (REDACTED) Initialize Soda [locale: %s]
12-28 05:23:00.273 +0000 16481 25697 W A       : (REDACTED) %s
12-28 05:23:00.274 +0000 16481 16560 I A       : Initialize Soda with language pack directory
12-28 05:23:00.277 +0000 16481 16560 I A       : Creating new SodaSharedResources
12-28 05:23:00.278 +0000 16481 16560 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.277941   16560 soda_async_impl.cc:358] Creating soda_impl.
12-28 05:23:00.278 +0000 16481 25694 I A       : (REDACTED) S3Request:
12-28 05:23:00.278 +0000 16481 25694 I A       : %s
12-28 05:23:00.281 +0000 16481 25701 W native  : W0000 00:00:1672204980.281442   25701 enrollment_manager_impl.cc:959] Failed to get cache folder:INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cache path is empty
12-28 05:23:00.281 +0000 16481 25701 W native  : === Source Location Trace: === 
12-28 05:23:00.281 +0000 16481 25701 W native  : speech/soda/speaker_id/enrollment/enrollment_manager_impl.cc:147
12-28 05:23:00.281 +0000 16481 25701 W native  : W0000 00:00:1672204980.281885   25701 enrollment_manager_impl.cc:977] SODA EnrollmentManager disabled.
12-28 05:23:00.282 +0000 16481 25701 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.282001   25701 enrollment_storage.cc:635] Storage cleared:OK
12-28 05:23:00.282 +0000 16481 16560 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.282451   16560 soda_async_impl.cc:1797] Updated speaker id profiles.
12-28 05:23:00.282 +0000 16481 16560 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.282658   16560 soda_impl.cc:289] Maximum audio history: 30s
12-28 05:23:00.282 +0000 16481 16560 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.282893   16560 soda_impl.cc:313] Adding Resampler from 16000 to 16000
12-28 05:23:00.285 +0000 16481 16560 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.285134   16560 soda_impl.cc:531] Enabling power evaluator.
12-28 05:23:00.285 +0000 16481 16560 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.285336   16560 soda_impl.cc:541] Adding preamble processor.
12-28 05:23:00.285 +0000 16481 16560 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.285432   16560 soda_impl.cc:570] Enabling On Device ASR
12-28 05:23:00.285 +0000 16481 16560 W native  : W0000 00:00:1672204980.285650   16560 language_pack_utils.cc:122] Error reading from /data/user/0/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/app_g3_models/fr-FR/configs: error 'No such file or directory' while opening directory '/data/user/0/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/app_g3_models/fr-FR/configs': No such file or directory
12-28 05:23:00.286 +0000 16481 16560 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.286495   16560 terse_processor.cc:1136] LP details: [locale: fr-fr, version: 401, config file: /data/user/0/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/app_g3_models/fr-FR/dictation.config, personalized resources dir: <NONE>]
12-28 05:23:00.289 +0000 16481 16560 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.288266   16560 terse_processor.cc:234] Loaded PipelineDef.
12-28 05:23:00.293 +0000 16481 25695 I ALT.AudioRecordSource: (REDACTED) #audio# create audio stream for audio record source(identity(%s), recordId(%d))
12-28 05:23:00.306 +0000 16481 16588 I ALT.AudioEventsHolder: (REDACTED) #audio# audio request client(token(%d)) session(token(%d)) start listening status(%s)
12-28 05:23:00.306 +0000 16481 16573 I A       : (REDACTED) #audio# AudioRequestListeningSession start listening status: %s
12-28 05:23:00.306 +0000 16481 16588 I A       : #audio# reportMicUpdate
12-28 05:23:00.338 +0000 16481 25697 I A       : (REDACTED) Playing beep %s (size %d bytes)
12-28 05:23:00.421 +0000 16481 25695 I ALT.FirstByteReporter: (REDACTED) #audio# mark first byte read result as non-empty, %dms spent reading
12-28 05:23:00.625 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:00.632 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : Audio track end of file reached
12-28 05:23:00.633 +0000 16481 16481 D AudioTrack: stop() called with 4313 frames delivered
12-28 05:23:00.640 +0000 16481 16560 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.640115   16560 terse_processor.cc:251] Initialized ResourceManager.
12-28 05:23:00.641 +0000 16481 16560 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.640995   16560 terse_processor.cc:263] Initialized GoogleRecognizer.
12-28 05:23:00.641 +0000 16481 16560 W native  : W0000 00:00:1672204980.641629   16560 terse_processor.cc:370] TISID disabled.
12-28 05:23:00.641 +0000 16481 16560 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.641680   16560 terse_processor.cc:1228] Domain: CAPTION
12-28 05:23:00.642 +0000 16481 16560 W native  : W0000 00:00:1672204980.642507   16560 context_session_resource.cc:120] ContextAwareModel context_model cannot process the following RecognitionContext:
12-28 05:23:00.642 +0000 16481 16560 W native  : MessageLite at 0xbdb05900
12-28 05:23:00.643 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:00.647 +0000 16481 16560 E native  : E0000 00:00:1672204980.647483   16560 ngram_fst_state.cc:58] Unigram state not found
12-28 05:23:00.654 +0000 16481 16560 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.653812   16560 terse_processor.cc:2305] Resetting Terse Processor
12-28 05:23:00.654 +0000 16481 16560 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.654230   16560 terse_processor.cc:1367] Cancelling session.
12-28 05:23:00.658 +0000 16481 16560 W native  : W0000 00:00:1672204980.658625   16560 decoder_endpointer_stream.cc:58] Acoustic ep reader thread cancelled.
12-28 05:23:00.659 +0000 16481 16560 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.659872   16560 terse_processor.cc:1267] Setup completed
12-28 05:23:00.660 +0000 16481 16560 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.659989   16560 soda_impl.cc:660] Server ASR Disabled
12-28 05:23:00.660 +0000 16481 16560 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.660029   16560 soda_impl.cc:737] Initializing audio logger
12-28 05:23:00.660 +0000 16481 16560 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.660077   16560 audio_logging_manager.cc:187] Using in-memory storage due to cache settings.
12-28 05:23:00.660 +0000 16481 16560 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.660584   16560 soda_async_impl.cc:520] Will attempt to run SODA at thread priority 10
12-28 05:23:00.660 +0000 16481 16560 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.660675   16560 hybrid_selector_impl.cc:89] HybridSelector: Disabled
12-28 05:23:00.660 +0000 16481 25714 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.660702   25714 audio_logging_manager.cc:1286] Cleaned storage:OK
12-28 05:23:00.661 +0000 16481 16560 I A       : (REDACTED) Initialized SODA with status: %s
12-28 05:23:00.661 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:00.662 +0000 16481 16558 I A       : Offline recognizer - start detection
12-28 05:23:00.663 +0000 16481 16558 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.663561   16558 soda_client.cc:273] Starting capture.
12-28 05:23:00.663 +0000 16481 16558 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.663735   16558 soda_client.cc:314] Loopback Provider config not present. Skipping Loopback
12-28 05:23:00.663 +0000 16481 16558 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.663810   16558 soda_async_impl.cc:639] SODA session starting (require_hotword:0, hotword_timeout_in_millis:0, trigger_type:TRIGGER_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED, hybrid_asr_config.mode:MODE_DEFAULT)
12-28 05:23:00.664 +0000 16481 16558 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.664010   16558 soda_async_impl.cc:918] Session parameters updated. Reconfiguring SODA.
12-28 05:23:00.664 +0000 16481 16558 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.664803   16558 hybrid_selector_impl.cc:89] HybridSelector: Disabled
12-28 05:23:00.665 +0000 16481 16558 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.664968   16558 terse_processor.cc:1914] Setting impersonated speaker id to: <NONE>
12-28 05:23:00.665 +0000 16481 16558 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.665080   16558 soda_async_impl.cc:619] Nice value unchanged at 10. Not changing SODA thread.
12-28 05:23:00.666 +0000 16481 16556 I A       : Starting to push audio to Soda
12-28 05:23:00.667 +0000 16481 25699 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.666910   25699 hybrid_selector_impl.cc:97] StartSession
12-28 05:23:00.668 +0000 16481 25699 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.668070   25699 soda_async_impl.cc:1519] SODA received first mic audio buffer, size in bytes: 320, format: 1, channels: 1, : sample rate: 16000
12-28 05:23:00.668 +0000 16481 25699 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204980.668598   25699 terse_processor.cc:2149] No terse session, starting a new one on input audio.
12-28 05:23:00.671 +0000 16481 25699 W native  : W0000 00:00:1672204980.671232   25699 context_session_resource.cc:120] ContextAwareModel context_model cannot process the following RecognitionContext:
12-28 05:23:00.671 +0000 16481 25699 W native  : MessageLite at 0xe11b76c0
12-28 05:23:00.680 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:00.689 +0000 16481 25699 E native  : E0000 00:00:1672204980.689129   25699 ngram_fst_state.cc:58] Unigram state not found
12-28 05:23:00.708 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:01.181 +0000 16481 25699 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204981.181065   25699 soda_async_impl.cc:1228] Not receiving any loopback audio in 500ms. Last audio received time: 0, Current time in us: 1672204981181061
12-28 05:23:02.020 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:02.463 +0000 16481 16481 I chatty  : uid=10062 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search identical 20 lines
12-28 05:23:02.481 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:03.041 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:03.060 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:03.081 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:03.101 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:03.241 +0000 16481 16481 I chatty  : uid=10062 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search identical 7 lines
12-28 05:23:03.261 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:03.460 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:03.521 +0000 16481 16481 I chatty  : uid=10062 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search identical 3 lines
12-28 05:23:03.560 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:03.640 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:03.660 +0000 16481 16481 I chatty  : uid=10062 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search identical 1 line
12-28 05:23:03.681 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:03.700 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:03.721 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:03.821 +0000 16481 16481 I chatty  : uid=10062 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search identical 5 lines
12-28 05:23:04.081 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:04.089 +0000 16481 16481 D ViewRootImpl@dae9332[InputMethod]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
12-28 05:23:04.101 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:04.120 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : (REDACTED) #setSpeechLevel %d
12-28 05:23:04.179 +0000 16481 16481 D ViewRootImpl@dae9332[InputMethod]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
12-28 05:23:04.181 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : #closeMicrophone
12-28 05:23:04.182 +0000 16481 16481 I ALT.ARCSession: (REDACTED) #audio# stop(reason(%s)) listening audio request client(token(%d)) session(token(%d))
12-28 05:23:04.183 +0000 16481 16481 I ALT.ARCSessionMgr: (REDACTED) #audio# stop(reason(%s)) listening audio request session(token(%d))
12-28 05:23:04.184 +0000 16481 16481 I ALT.SourceMgr: #audio# stopListening
12-28 05:23:04.184 +0000 16481 16481 I ALT.SourceSequencer: (REDACTED) #audio# close audio source(%s)
12-28 05:23:04.185 +0000 16481 25697 I ALT.AudioRecordSource: (REDACTED) #audio# close audio source(identity(%s), recordId(%d))
12-28 05:23:04.185 +0000 16481 16481 I ALT.AFCSession: (REDACTED) #audio# release audio focus session(token(%d))
12-28 05:23:04.186 +0000 16481 25695 I ALT.BytesAccessorBuffer: (REDACTED) #audio# mark buffer(%s) closed, available bytes(%d)
12-28 05:23:04.188 +0000 16481 16556 W A       : #audio# read failed: read EOF from AudioAccessor.
12-28 05:23:04.188 +0000 16481 25696 W A       : #audio# read failed: read EOF from AudioAccessor.
12-28 05:23:04.188 +0000 16481 16556 I A       : Sending end of audio to Soda.
12-28 05:23:04.189 +0000 16481 25699 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204984.188958   25699 soda_async_impl.cc:1129] SODA stopped processing audio, mics audio processed in millis: 3780, loopback audio processed in millis: 0
12-28 05:23:04.189 +0000 16481 25715 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204984.188938   25715 audio_provider_reader.cc:163] Got end of data in: micsreader
12-28 05:23:04.189 +0000 16481 16588 I A       : startDetection successful
12-28 05:23:04.189 +0000 16481 25699 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204984.189760   25699 terse_processor.cc:1946] Flushing pending events ..
12-28 05:23:04.190 +0000 16481 25699 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204984.190000   25699 terse_processor.cc:1962] Start longform loop on remaining audio: 3.78s
12-28 05:23:04.191 +0000 16481 25694 W A       : #audio# read failed: read EOF from AudioAccessor.
12-28 05:23:04.192 +0000 16481 16573 I A       : (REDACTED) Audio focus releasing status: %s
12-28 05:23:04.194 +0000 16481 16596 I ALT.AudioEventsHolder: (REDACTED) #audio# audio focus session(token(%d)) release status(%s)
12-28 05:23:04.214 +0000 16481 16588 I A       : (REDACTED) #audio# AudioRequestListeningSession stop listening status: %s
12-28 05:23:04.214 +0000 16481 16573 I ALT.AudioEventsHolder: (REDACTED) #audio# audio request client(token(%d)) session(token(%d)) stop listening status(%s)
12-28 05:23:04.214 +0000 16481 16591 I A       : (REDACTED) Mic closing result: %s
12-28 05:23:04.214 +0000 16481 16573 I A       : #audio# reportMicUpdate
12-28 05:23:04.294 +0000 16481 25699 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204984.294191   25699 terse_processor.cc:2545] TerseProcessor HasRecognitionEvent With Final
12-28 05:23:04.294 +0000 16481 25719 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204984.294174   25719 terse_processor.cc:836] Final recognition has been created.
12-28 05:23:04.294 +0000 16481 25699 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204984.294577   25699 terse_processor.cc:1986] Stop looping and end session. Audio left: 30ms
12-28 05:23:04.302 +0000 16481 25699 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204984.302101   25699 soda_impl.cc:1354] Got pipeline signal out
12-28 05:23:04.302 +0000 16481 25699 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204984.302838   25699 soda_async_impl.cc:1618] Ending ASR due to process sync signal.
12-28 05:23:04.302 +0000 16481 25699 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204984.302886   25699 hybrid_selector_impl.cc:143] EndSession
12-28 05:23:04.302 +0000 16481 25699 W native  : W0000 00:00:1672204984.302915   25699 hybrid_selector_impl.cc:145] No active session.
12-28 05:23:04.303 +0000 16481 25699 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204984.303198   25699 terse_processor.cc:2305] Resetting Terse Processor
12-28 05:23:04.303 +0000 16481 25699 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204984.303276   25699 metrics_utils.cc:298] Unhandled metrics event type: SODA_PROCESS_LATENCY
12-28 05:23:04.303 +0000 16481 25699 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204984.303338   25699 soda_async_impl.cc:1186] SODA session stopped due to: MIC_END_OF_DATA
12-28 05:23:04.310 +0000 16481 16593 I A       : (REDACTED) TTL (%d seconds) reached - destroy SODA
12-28 05:23:04.326 +0000 16481 16593 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204984.326908   16593 soda_async_impl.cc:1258] Deleted soda_impl.
12-28 05:23:04.327 +0000 16481 25700 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204984.327336   25700 soda_jni_event_delegate.cc:95] Done
12-28 05:23:04.328 +0000 16481 16593 I native  : I0000 00:00:1672204984.328083   16593 enrollment_manager_impl.cc:1910] Shutting down ..
12-28 05:23:04.399 +0000 16481 16596 I A       : Received a final result for a segment
12-28 05:23:04.399 +0000 16481 16596 I A       : Received the final result for the recognition
12-28 05:23:04.401 +0000 16481 16573 I A       : Offline recognizer - stop detection
12-28 05:23:04.420 +0000 16481 25697 I A       : (REDACTED) Playing beep %s (size %d bytes)
12-28 05:23:04.421 +0000 16481 18532 I cr_CronetUrlRequestContext: destroyNativeStreamLocked org.chromium.net.impl.CronetBidirectionalStream@40adef8
12-28 05:23:04.852 +0000 16481 16481 I A       : Audio track end of file reached
12-28 05:23:04.853 +0000 16481 16481 D AudioTrack: stop() called with 6788 frames delivered
12-28 05:23:09.408 +0000 16481 16590 I A       : #failWithException
12-28 05:23:09.410 +0000 16481 16590 W A       : (REDACTED) #onError space %s code %d!
12-28 05:23:09.411 +0000 16481 16590 W A       : #onError already finished - ignoring
```

Comment: Typically user input should not be written to any log file as it can contain sensitive data. If your device is rooted you could try to attach to the corresponding app/process using https://Frida.re but that will require some Java and JavaScript development experience as you have to decompile the app e.g. using Jadx, identify the correct methods and then write a Frida-Hook to retrieve the data.